# Android Studio 2.1.2 can't run app after changes

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, fatal-error, runtimeexception

Please help me restart my app after changes.
When I try to change some method signature and try to run app I have a stable fatal exception, but if I clean project and rebuild app all works (once), this procedure i need to do all time after changes.

logcat:

```
08-02 22:11:27.157 8303-8303/com.hellopal.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hellopal.android, PID: 8303
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.hellopal.android.ProgramController: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.hellopal.android.ProgramController" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hellopal.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.hellopal.android-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:171)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.hellopal.android.ProgramController" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.hellopal.android-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.hellopal.android-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:171) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you tried to disable **Instant Run** feature ?